# ListView doesnt load items

Tags: android, listview

I create a ListView in my fragment and getting the result from a simple string list.

Item.java

```
public class Item implements Parcelable  {

    public String message;

    public Item(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }


    protected Item(Parcel in) {
        message = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<Item> CREATOR = new Creator<Item>() {
        @Override
        public Item createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Item(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Item[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Item[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(message);
    }
}
```

item_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/item_text"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

ListAdapter.java

```
public class ItemListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

    public ItemListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> items) {
        super(context, 0, items);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get the data item for this position
        Item item = getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);
        }

        TextView messageText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_text);

        messageText.setText(item.message);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

BeveragesItemListFragment.java

```
public class BeveragesItemListFragment extends ListFragment {

    private ArrayList<Item> array_of_items = new ArrayList<>();;
    private List<String> bevs = Arrays.asList("קולה", "קולה זירו", "דיאט קולה", "נסטי אפרסק");

    public BeveragesItemListFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);

        TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_title);
        title.setText("שתיה קלה");

        ItemListAdapter adapter = new ItemListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), array_of_items);

        for (String bev: bevs) {
            Item newItem = new Item(bev);
            adapter.add(newItem);
        }

        return v;
    }
}
```

The application doesn't crash - The fragment loads with its title and everything looks fine log-wise. However, i don't see the predefined strings, in the ListView. Maybe the problem is with the context i passed in `ItemListAdapter` initialization?

I've tried putting `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to call  [`setListAdapter(adapter);`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html#setListAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)) before `return v;`

```
   ItemListAdapter adapter = new ItemListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), array_of_items);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
    return v;
```

and change `android:layout_height="match_parent"` to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to make room for other list items

Answer (score 0):

Just set your adapter into `ListView` via `ListView.setAdapter`. Adapter by itself won't display anything.

Answer (score 0):

you need to put the below line above the return statement.

```
for (String bev: bevs) {
            Item newItem = new Item(bev);
            array_of_items.add(newItem);
        }

ItemListAdapter adapter = new ItemListAdapter(getActivity(), array_of_items);


    setListAdapter(adapter);
```